# TypeError: $.ajax(...).done(...).fail(...).complete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-3

I suddenly started getting the following:

> TypeError: $.ajax(...).done(...).fail(...).complete is not a function

My code:

```
this.sendRequest = function (type, extension, data, successCallback, successMsg, failMsg, failCallback) {

            var self = this;
            var options = {
                url: self.baseUrl + self.apiEndpoint + extension,
                type: type,
                dataType: 'json',
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                }
            };
            if (data != null) {
                options.data = data;
            }
            return $.ajax(options)
                .done(function (response) {
                    // do stuff
                })
                .fail(function (response) {
                    // do stuff
                }).complete(function (response) {
                    // do stuff
                });
        };
```

Why is this happening?  I did update jQuery - did some of this syntax become invalidated?

Comment: Yes; `complete` was deprecated as of jQuery 3.0

Comment: @Hamms what should I use instead?

Comment: `always`; the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) also have this information

Answer (score 12):

`.complete` is deprecated....use `.always`

> **jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });** (added in jQuery 1.6)
>
> An alternative construct to the complete callback option, the .always() method **replaces the deprecated .complete() method**.